# How to add background colour change throughout the page?

Tags: html, background

Please give some suggestions, I`m new to HTML5 so I need more advice from experts around the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML do not support the  tag bgcolor attribute, so the CSS style is used to add background color, not HTML.

### For the different types of CSS:

To set the background color in HTML using inline CSS, use the style attribute in the body tag, like this:

```
<body style = "background-color: blue">
   <p> Background color is blue using Inline CSS! </p>
</body>
```

To set the background color in HTML using internal CSS, use the style tag in the head, like this:

```
<head>
   <style>
      background-color: blue;
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <p> Background color is blue using internal CSS! </p>
</body>
```

To set the background color in HTML using external CSS, simply write 'background-color' in the file, like this:

(In the CSS)

```
background-color: blue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a smooth transition or a blockier style? CSS `linear-gradient();` might be what you’re looking for. Check out the MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()

Answer (score 0):

Just style the background colour of the body tag using CSS like this:

```html
<body style="background-color: black;">
</body>
```